# Towel bar above wall-mounted convection heater

Tags: heater, bathroom-fixtures

I am building a cozy bathroom in my basement. Due to the limited space, I am planning to install a towel bar directly above a wall mounted convection heater.

Should I be worried of fire hazards of this installation?

How high above the heater should the towel bar be installed?

Comment: What is the source of heat for the convector (i.e. electric resistance bars - serious fire potential. Hot water or steam, essentially no fire potential.)

Comment: It is electric. This is the device I'm looking to get: https://www.dimplex.com/en/convection_heaters/products/dep_series/panel_convector_series

Comment: I'm guessing there are no electrical heating device that would be considered safe for this application. Correct?

Comment: Some are safe-er - I.e. resistance elements that visibly glow orange (bare - or the UK usage "electric fire") are considerably more hazardous than "Oil-filled" units where the resistance element is inside a larger surround that's heated by the oil (that's heated by the electric element) but surface temperature is more limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On product description:

Key Features and Benefits
**Top discharge** provides powerful convection airflow

From User Manual:
5. To prevent a possible fire, **do not block the air
intakes or exhaust in any manner**.